# Symfony 2 Validation Form

Tags: forms, validation, symfony, bind

I am new and I need some help.

I have a problem when I try to validate my form.

Below my different files:

AmiAttrbType.php

```
<?php

namespace Site\TestBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

 class AmiAttrbType extends AbstractType
  {

  /**
   * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
   * @param array $options
   */
   public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
   {
      $builder
        ->add('email','text', array(
            'required' => true,
            'attr' => array(
            'placeholder' => 'Adresse Mail'
        )))
        ->add('produitsAttrb','collection', array(
            'type' => new ProduitAttrbType()
        ));
    }

   /**
   * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
   */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Site\TestBundle\Entity\Ami'
        ));
    }

    /**
    * @return string
    */
    public function getName()
    {
      return 'site_testbundle_amiAttrb';
    }
}
```

ProduitAttrbType.php

```
<?php

namespace Site\TestBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class ProduitAttrbType extends AbstractType
{

    /**
   * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
   * @param array $options
   */
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {

        $builder
            ->add('nom', 'hidden')
            ->add('qte','integer', array(
            'required' => true
            ));
  }

  /**
   * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
   */
  public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
  {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Site\TestBundle\Entity\ProduitAttrb'
    ));
  }

  /**
   * @return string
   */
  public function getName()
  {
    return 'site_testbundle_produitAttrb';
  }
}
```

controller.php

```
public function attrbAction(Event $commande)
{   
   $ami = new Ami;

   foreach($commande->getProduits() as $produit)
   {
      $ami->addProduitsAttrb(new ProduitAttrb($produit->getNom(),0));
   }

   $form = $this->createForm(new AmiAttrbType(),$ami);


   $request = $this->get('request');

   if( $this->get('request')->getMethod() == 'POST' )
   {  
       $form->bind($request);

       if ($form->isValid())
       {

           $commande->addAmi($ami);

           $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
           $em->merge($commande);

           $em->flush();

            return $this->render('SiteTestBundle:Test:attrb.html.twig', array('commande' =>$commande, 'form' => $form->createView()));
      }
   } 

    return $this->render('SiteTestBundle:Test:attrb.html.twig', array('commande' =>$commande, 'form' => $form->createView()));
}
```

attrb.html.twig:

```
<tr>
    <td  class="attrb-new">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
               {{ form_widget(form.email) }}
             </div>
       </div>
   </td>
   {% for produit in form.produitsAttrb %}
      <td class="attrb-newQte">
        {{ form_widget(produit.qte) }}
       </td>
    {% endfor %}
   {{ form_rest(form) }}
</tr>
```

I have two case:
If, in the controller, I use bind($request), I have two errors:

```
- Email empty (email has been entered)
- Token invalid (token exist in my source code)
```

I don't understand why I have this errors.

If I use `handleRequest($request)`, nothing is happening.

My symfony version is higher 2.3 but bindhas always worked.

When I remove this part in my twig code and I have `bind($request)`:

```
{% for produit in form.produitsAttrb %}
      <td class="attrb-newQte">
        {{ form_widget(produit.qte) }}
      </td>
{% endfor %}
```

It's works.

Please can you help me.

Thank you in advance.

regards

Answer (score 0):

You should pass Request object to action instead of getting it from service. like this:

```
public function testAction(Request $request, $myOtherArgs)
{
    ....
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    ...
}
```

Also, if you want to see what's causing the error, you can var_dump the form after calling the `handleRequest`:

```
var_dump($form->getErrors(true));
```